# How to add comma thousand separator in Power BI [Query Editor]

Tags: format, powerbi

There is a column with numbers like :

```
ex.
12876391
```

Desired to convert like

```
12,876,391
```

in whole column.

I cannot find the simple solution in many forum .
How can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can first select the column in the `Fields` pane, and then find the `Thousands separator` options under `Modeling` -> `Formatting`.

[image: separator]

Comment: Its works, that exactly what i need very thank you so much .

Comment: My data source is an AAS model. So I do not have the option for formatting it through Modelling. Is there any way to solve this when I am using Direct Query mode?

Comment: What if the number is an aggregated count done by the visualization itself? For example dropping in a categorical column to a Multi-row Card and choosing Count (Distinct)

Answer (score 4):

I had a table of Google Analytics data, no Modelling > Format option was showing.
I went to the regular Format (paint roller) again no option except for Values > Decimal Places, which was on Auto and grayed out.

Then I discovered if you click on the actual metric you want to format in the data Fields area, lo and behold, you get two new tabs up top: Table Tools and Column Tools.
Column Tools has the usual Excel-type formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are best if they work for your situation, but if you really need to do this *within Power Query*, you can use this:

### fNumberToTextWithComma

```
(n as number) as text =>
let
    numberAsTextList = Text.Split(Number.ToText(Number.Abs(n), null, "en-US"), "."),
    textWhole = numberAsTextList{0},
    fNextRecordInListGenerate = each
            let
                len = Text.Length([remaining])
            in
                if len = 0 then
                    [remaining = null]
                else
                    [remaining = Text.Start([remaining], List.Max({0, len - 3})), part = Text.End([remaining], 3)],
    nums = List.Reverse(List.Generate(
        () => fNextRecordInListGenerate([remaining = textWhole, part = ""]),
        each [remaining] <> null,
        fNextRecordInListGenerate,
        each [part]
    )),
    ret = (if Number.Sign(n) = -1 then "-" else "")
        & Text.Combine(nums, ",")
        & (if List.Count = 1 then "" else "." & numberAsTextList{1})
in
    ret
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI - the solution provided by @JSmart523 is great, but has a bug. The last line should have List.Count(numberAsTextList) = 1, so the full code is:

```
    (n as number) as text =>
let
    numberAsTextList = Text.Split(Number.ToText(Number.Abs(n), null, "en-US"), "."),
    textWhole = numberAsTextList{0},
    fNextRecordInListGenerate = each
            let
                len = Text.Length([remaining])
            in
                if len = 0 then
                    [remaining = null]
                else
                    [remaining = Text.Start([remaining], List.Max({0, len - 3})), part = Text.End([remaining], 3)],
    nums = List.Reverse(List.Generate(
        () => fNextRecordInListGenerate([remaining = textWhole, part = ""]),
        each [remaining]  null,
        fNextRecordInListGenerate,
        each [part]
    )),
    ret = (if Number.Sign(n) = -1 then "-" else "")
        & Text.Combine(nums, ",")
        & (if List.Count(numberAsTextList) = 1 then "" else "." & numberAsTextList{1})
in
    ret
```