# How to add comma thousand separator shows error if number has ".00"

Tags: powerbi

[How to add comma thousand separator in Power BI [Query Editor]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49247661/how-to-add-comma-thousand-separator-in-power-bi-query-editor/64129304#64129304)

The above post was great. However when I have a number (to 2 decimal places) that ends in .00 it returns an error. For other numbers it works brilliantly.

What do I need to adjust so the numbers ending in ".00" work?

I've worked out it is in this line:

```
{numberAsTextList = Text.Split(Number.ToText(Number.Abs(n), null, "en-US"), ".")}
```

Comment: Apologies for not getting the code bit in the correct format

Answer (score 1):

I actually negated the need for a 'function', by just creating a new custom column using:

```
Number.ToText([put your reference column here],"N")
```

Funny thing is even the Microsoft site on `Number.ToText` doesn't give the "N" as an example. I managed to find it at
https://excelinexcel.in/ms-excel/powerquery-m/number-totext-function/